# AWS Elastic Beanstalk API call

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to to make a API call to AWS EB.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/api/API_DescribeApplications.html

```
https://elasticbeanstalk.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/?ApplicationNames.member.1=SampleApplication
&Operation=DescribeApplications
&AuthParams
```

What is the **AuthParams** and how to generate it?

Answer (score 1):

Authparams are your authorization header credentials from AWS, only by using that you can call any AWS API.

> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/CommonParameters.html

Check this URL for more information.